# Can't submit form without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I build a link shortener,just for fun!
Everything works, but everytime I create a link and submit the form, the page reloads! I wanted to prevent that with `onclick="return false;"`but it didnt work.

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Create!"  />

$('#contactForm').submit(function () {
    sendContactForm();
    return false;
});
```

But nothing works, the file is just stuck and doesn't do anything! What am I doing from ? This is the problem page https://viid.su
PHP

```
   require("db_config.php");
       $uid = 1;
      $flink = $_POST['url'];
      if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i", $flink)) {
        $html = "Error: invalid URL";
      } else {

        $db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

          $id = substr(md5(time().$flink), 0, 5);
          if($conn->query("INSERT INTO `".$database."`.`link` (`id`, `flink`,`adonly`,`userid`) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$flink."','true','".$uid."');")) {
            $html = 'Your short URL is <a class="test" href="https://viid.su/'.$id.'">https://viid.su/'.$id.'</a>';
          } else {
            $html = "Error: cannot find database";
          }
        mysqli_close($db);
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault(); ` ? Or you could use Ajax to submit it.

Comment: If you don't want to post a form at all and just want to do everything via JavaScript/AJAX then I imagine you could remove the `<form>` element entirely and just respond to the button's click event.  Then there'd be nothing to post.

Comment: David what do you mean ?

Comment: EduwHS it still reloads on mobile

Comment: @Leeroy: I mean don't use a `<form>` element.  Just have the `<input>` elements you want and the button.  Use jQuery to handle the button's click event to send the AJAX request.  Since you don't want to post a form, there's no need for a `<form>`.

Comment: What does `sendContactForm()` do?

Comment: yes but... I have problems with AJAX

Comment: @Leeroy Kindly mark an answer as best if it has solved your problem

Comment: nobody did solve my problem xD

Answer (score 1):

You can submit a form without reloading the page by using something like an AJAX call.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();        

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "path/to/your/script.php",
           data: $('#contactForm').serialize(), // Packs the form's elements
           success: function(data)
           {
               // Do something  here if the call succeeded
               alert(data);
           }
         });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="contactForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

echo $_POST['username'];

?>
```

Something along those lines should work, and you don't need anything else, as you are already using jQuery.

Comment: how I should echo the link ?

Comment: @Leeroy You can put the code you need using the link you retrieved (that is now into the data variable) inside the success function

Comment: @Leeroy It *does* work, you might be missing or mistaking something in your code.

Comment: @Leeroy See my last edit, I updated a few things you might have missed.

Comment: could you tell me how the input fields should look like

Comment: Yes, one second.

Comment: btw, I just tried something else, and now I put your version, don't be confused that it has  url: "path/to/your/script.php", I edited it before but it didn't work too

Comment: I had the same but it doesn't work, I don't know what I am doing wrong..

Comment: btw, it generates the link id in the ajax file like https://viid.su/947d3, so I can't use the variable that I posted

Comment: @Leeroy Are you sure the path to your PHP file is correct?

Comment: yes, I can update the question and add the php code ok

Comment: @Leeroy Yes, that would help.

Comment: @Leeroy Apparently that's an error with your MySQL code and page/link creation. I'd suggest you to create another question since currently it goes beyond the actual question.

Comment: but where is the error ? like if would use my form again, it would work

Comment: yeah, me too anyway I will go to bed and work on it tomorrow... good night and thank you for helping andrey !

Answer (score 0):

you need to use event object as parameter in function callback and call event.preventDefault()

Comment: `return false;` is equivalent to calling `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `<input type="submit" />` into something like `<button onclick="return false;" id="shortenLinkButton">Send</button>`

Then with jQuery you can catch the even like this:

```
// This code will be usable after the page has fully loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Catch the onclick event
  $('#shortenLinkButton').on('click', function() {
    // do something
    alert('clicked the button, do your ajax stuff here after retrieving the data from the input');
  });
});
```